# maximum number of levels in a binary tree of leafs n

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I want to know the maximum no of levels in a binary tree of which the total leaf nodes are n . Nothing has been said about type of binary tree ,just it is a binary tree

Comment: This question is more about mathematics(?). When I draw n leaves and the upper nodes I always get a number of level equals to n/2 which is because it is a binary tree (2). Is it what you were asking for?

Comment: You can increase a tree with `n` leaf nodes (without restriction on total number of nodes) as much as you want, by "pushing" an internal node between some internal node to its parent on the path to the deepest node.

Comment: I can draw a tree of depth 2 that has 2 leaf nodes, and I can draw a tree of 1,000,000 levels that has 2 leaf nodes. Given no restrictions on the shape of the tree, there is no upper limit on the depth of a tree with `n` leaf nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Binary tree**: a rooted tree where each node has 0, 1, or 2 children.

**Full binary tree**: a binary tree where each node has 0 or 2 children.

**Perfect binary tree**: a full binary tree where each leaf has the same depth.

The level of a tree is the depth plus 1. The depth of a binary tree with n leaves can be from [image: formula] to infinite. The depth of a full binary tree can be from [image: formula] to [image: formula]. The lower bound in these two cases is when it is a perfect binary tree.